# Cyclic buffer written in native c win32

Tags: c, winapi, stream, buffer

I need a good implementation of a (thread safe) cyclic buffer written in c.
Does anybody know where i can get it?

thanks!

Comment: Oh the tricks you can play with memory mappings to make ring buffers more efficient...

Comment: You will get better google hits if you use the proper term: +"circular buffer".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked at [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer) wikipedia record? They give an example, and have more external links.

As for thread-safe access just wrap the object with your own if needed, and throw a lock() / unlock() at it.